# $\sin(A-B)\geq \sin(A)-\sin(B)$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Just out of interest, I was experimenting different angles of $A$, $B$ such that $0\leq A\leq B\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and it seems to me that everytime this following inequality holds:

$$\sin(A-B)\geq \sin(A)-\sin(B).$$

I was wondering why is this the case? I feel like I am just missing something really trivial. I tried to use double angle formula but I was stuck when bounding $\sin(A) \cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)$.

Could someone please point it out what is missing for me? Thank you so much!!

Comment: $\sin(x-y) - \sin(x) - \sin(y) = -4 \cos(\dfrac{x}{2}) \sin(\dfrac{y}{2}) \cos(\dfrac{1}{2} (x - y))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly the other way around: For $0\leq A\leq B\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ is
$$
 \sin(B) - \sin(A) = 2 \cos\left( \frac{B+A}{2}\right)\sin\left( \frac{B-A}{2}\right) \\
\le  2 \cos\left( \frac{B-A}{2}\right)\sin\left( \frac{B-A}{2}\right) = \sin(B-A) \, ,
$$
using a [sum-to-product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) and a [double-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle,_triple-angle,_and_half-angle_formulae).
The inequality holds because $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, \pi/2]$.

Multiplication with $(-1)$ gives
$$
\sin(A) - \sin(B) \ge \sin(A-B) \, .
$$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this holds even for $0\leq A\leq B\leq\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot prove it, since it is not true. If $B=\frac\pi2$ and $0<A<\frac\pi2$, then\begin{align}\sin(A-B)-\sin(A)+\sin(B)&=\sin\left(A-\frac\pi2\right)-\sin(A)+1\\&=1-\cos(A)-\sin(A)\\&=1-\sqrt2\cos\left(A-\frac\pi4\right)\\&<0.\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

As noted in other answers, OP has the inequality (or else the angles) reversed. Here's trigonographic proof:

[image]

$$0\leq A\leq B\leq 90^\circ \qquad\to\qquad\sin(B-A)\;\geq\;\sin B-\sin A$$

Comment: That is actually a super cool picture! Thank you for sharing!